# How to catch event when touched outside the Dialog

Tags: android

I have a `dialog` for my application. I want to `catch event` when the user `clicks outside` the `dialog`. What do I have to do for this?

This is my code, but it did not run.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();`enter code here`
    int xmargin = (ViewUtils.getScreenWidth() - Constants.PRODUCT_DIALOG_WIDTH) / 2;
    int ymargin = (ViewUtils.getScreenHeight() - Constants.PRODUCT_DIALOG_HEIGHT) / 2;

    if (
            x < xmargin|| 
            x > ViewUtils.getScreenWidth() - xmargin ||
            y < ymargin|| 
            y > ViewUtils.getScreenHeight() - ymargin
        ) {
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Thank all!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code, for event when you touch outside a dialog -

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        dialog.show();
```

Hope this helps.